# Фоторедактор android

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Возник такой вопрос. Необходимо сделать приложение, в котором можно было бы редактировать фото по-минимуму. Добавлять различным надписи, изменять у них цвета\шрифты, добавлять абстрактные фигуры и проч. Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека графического редактора, которую можно было бы использовать в проекте, или придется все самому писать руками с нуля? Если у кого есть опыт, поделитесь- сложно написать такой простенький фоторедактор?

Ещё в приложении должна быть функция встраивания в написанный пользователем текст различным палочек, картинок и т.д. Вопрос аналогичный- может есть какая-нибудь библиотека? Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Рисуйте на канве. Это все вообще легко, погуглите: Android Canvas